# Script That Checks For Newly Installed Software

Tags: deb

Is there some service or event that is created when the deb installer installs new software?  I want to create desktop shortcuts everytime a new app is installed.  I know how to do the shortcut, I just want to know if there is an event I can tie to that part of the script.

Answer (score 2):

- Workaround: If you use unity, when you install software using the software-center (ubuntu software center), there's a note at the bottom of the window asking you if you want to create a unity launcher. You can click "Yes" or "No" accordingly.
- On the other hand, you could create some script that checks the log file:

  ```
  cat /var/log/dpkg.log|grep installed
  ```
- There are triggers, but as far as I can read, they are incorporated in debian packages:

  ```
  man debian-trigger deb-triggers
  ```

  (I wonder how desktop-file-utils triggers dpkg: *Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils*)

  ```
  less /usr/share/doc/dpkg-dev/triggers.txt.gz
  ls /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/
  ```
- Finally, maybe you could use dnotify for your script and watch the /usr/share/applications directory, where .desktop files are saved:

  https://serverfault.com/questions/50127/how-to-automatically-run-a-script-when-the-contents-of-a-directory-changes-in-li

Comment: For triggers, here is nice post how to use them.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276535/dpkg-how-to-use-trigger. They can be used to watch a folder, in OP case `interest /usr/share/applications`